# How do I browse between my portal keys

Tags: ingress

In items screen I see `Portal Keys (2)`- that I have 2 keys. However it seems I can only select, view or get a fix on the first portal. I don't see any way to select or view the second key. (which means I can recharge the first portal from anywhere but not the second)

How do I access the other keys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see Portal Keys (2), that means that you have two of the same portal key, not two different ones.  Keys for each portal appear as separate items.